# Mongoose sort by date when using $project, $frequency and $group

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The query below returns data aggregated for each week in no particular order. I'd like to see them in date order old to new.

createdTime is type Date.

I expect the results to be in week order eg 49, 50, 51, 52, 00, 01, 02 etc

```
{
  "aggregate": [
    {
      "$project": {
        "frequency": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "format": "%U",
            "date": "$createdTime"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id":"$frequency",
        "count": {
          "$sum": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But they come back in random order (where _id is the week number):

```
{    
{
        "_id": "52",
        "count": 51
    },
    {
        "_id": "07",
        "count": 4103
    },
    {
        "_id": "51",
        "count": 2608
    },
    {
        "_id": "49",
        "count": 69599
    },
    {
        "_id": "01",
        "count": 4418
    }
}
```

How can i sort this by date? I've tried adding sort in many places but to no avail.

Comment: you want this ordered by week number or createdTime?

Comment: Either, but it has to be in order as the dates go into the new year so weeks 51, 52 will come before 00, 01 thats why i thought it might require createdTime. I also tried putting a $first condition then i could use that date and filter in the UI but failed

Comment: but you are grouping by week, years are not included. All you will get is 00 to 52 grouped for all possible years.

Comment: but this is no good if 1) they come back in random order 2) i don't know if week x is in 2017 or 2018. Surely the createDate (Date object ) could be used to order them or at least append the first or last date in the frequency. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you.

```
{
      "aggregate": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "frequency": {
               $concat:[{
              "$dateToString": {
                "format": "%Y",
                "date": "$createdTime"
              },{
              "$dateToString": {
                "format": "%U",
                "date": "$createdTime"
              }]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id":"$frequency",
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },{$sort:{_id:-1}}
      ]
    }
```

Output will be something like below

```
{   
    {
        "_id": "201807",
        "count": 4103
    },
    {
        "_id": "201801",
        "count": 4418
    },
    {
        "_id": "201752",
        "count": 51
    },
    {
        "_id": "201751",
        "count": 2608
    },
    {
        "_id": "201749",
        "count": 69599
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry mate doesn't quite work, it's giving back months 7,8,9 for jan, feb. I think i need to change tact on this one, shouldn't be this difficult.